# Conjugation maps - Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory

> Consider the algebraic number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{13})$. I want to answer the following questions:

> (1) What are the conjugation maps on $K$?

> (2) Prove that $\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}\in\mathbb{O}_K$, and use this to prove that $\{1,\sqrt{13}\}$ is not an integral basis for $\mathbb{O}_K$.

> (3) Determine the discriminant of the basis $\left\{1,\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right\}$, and prove it is an integral basis for $\mathbb{O}_K$.

Attempt: (1) A general element of $K$ is $a+b\sqrt{13}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. The two conjugation maps are $\sigma_1(a+b\sqrt{13})=a+b\sqrt{13}$ and $\sigma_2(a+b\sqrt{13})=a-b\sqrt{13}$.

(2) By definition we have $\mathbb{O}_K$ is the set of algebraic integers in $K$, so we need to prove that $\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ is an algebraic integer. Write $X=\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$. Then, $2X-1=\sqrt{13}$ and upon squaring we get $4X^2-4X+1=13$. Thus $4X^2-4X-12=0$, and so $X^2-X-3=0$. This is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients with $\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ as a root, and by definition is an algebraic integer. Therefore $\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}\in\mathbb{O}_K$ as claimed.

However I don't know how this proves $\{1,\sqrt{13}\}$ isn't an integral basis though.

(3) The basis $\left\{1,\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right\}$ has matrix representation as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}\\1&\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The discriminant of the basis is the square of the determinant of this matrix, which is $(\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}-\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}(1-\sqrt{13}-(1+\sqrt{13}))^2=\frac{1}{4}(2\sqrt{13})^2=13$, which is square-free and so this is an integral basis.

Are these answers correct?

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}+\sqrt{13}\Bbb{Z}=\Bbb{Z}+(1+\sqrt{13})\Bbb{Z}$ clearly has index $2$ in $\Bbb{Z}+\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}2\Bbb{Z}$. Yes if a (full-rank) subgroup $L\subset O_K$ has square-free discriminant then it must be the whole of $O_K$.

Comment: @reuns Sorry I'm not sure what you mean, could you elaborate please?

Comment: If $u,v\in \Bbb{C}$ are $\Bbb{Q}$-linearly independent then $u\Bbb{Z}+2v\Bbb{Z}$ has index $2$ in $u\Bbb{Z}+v\Bbb{Z}$ (ie. the quotient of the latter by the former has two elements)